# Validation(HTML5): Element 'T' is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a web application in MVC5.

And I am trying to use model in View as shown in snapshot -

[image]

Faced problem for *model* too. I tried some solutions as (but none fixed it) -

**(1)** Delete all files of folder at location *E:\Users\V.S. Saini\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas* based on root drive and the Visual Studio version installed.

Since I am using VS 2012, so the path is.

**(2)** There was a solution suggesting upgrade of razor version from 2.0 to 3.0 in web.config in Views. But not worked.

***Could you please help me to fix this issue?***

Comment: Have you tried adding a '@using System' in the view?

Comment: @Anon Tried that too. The reference is not an issue. Because I can build website and all working fine. But the VS 2012 showing validation message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well! It was daunting task to fix this issue.*

First of all this mess was created *due to updating different MVC related references* (v4 to v5) from **Nuget Package Manager** in VS 2012.

### Steps as solution

**(1)** The first and utmost task is to cross-check your existing web.config (both in root and Views folder) as per the link [How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2).

**(2)** Then downloaded the update at link [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx). Close all Visual Studio instances and then run this update.

**(3)** Open Visual Studio and re-build MVC solution.

*Wow! The squiggy error line got removed and VS started recognizing razor keywords. :)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it's Visual Studio isn't picking up that `@model` is a special Razor keyword. The entire `@model` is normally highlighted yellow. And then `List` shouldn't be black to match the text color, it should be the color for classes.

[image: screenshot of visual studio highlighting]

Have you tried running Visual Studio in safe mode to see if a plugin or extension is causing this issue? As you stated in your comment, it probably isn't harming anything, but it probably is annoying.

Comment: I do agree with you for reason part of this issue. I tried running in /SafeMode but issue still persists. I believe there is something in web.config that is messing. But don't know what it is.

Comment: @V.S.Saini Have you created a blank MVC project and see if `@model List<string>` has the same issue in it?

Comment: Creating blank MVC project and using @model List<string> works fine because MVC version is 4. But it didn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know it's not an error!

Steps to resolve the warning message for an element.

1. Right click the warning area, you will see a context menu.
2. Click "Formatting and Validation..." basically it's at the bottom of the menu.
3. Go to "Validation" in "HTML or HTML (Web Forms)" section. You'll see a checkbox with "Show errors" is checked to true with header "Options". Just unchecke it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86V4o.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuEXT.png)

That's it, you are done...