# Validation(HTML5) : Element 'app-root' is not supported in .aspx webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, webforms

I am integrating Angular 8 with ASP.NET WebForm.

Created an angular folder using ng new AngularApp command and set default.aspx page as startpage.

I have included  tag inside Default.aspx page to call angular page, but it's not working for me.

I am getting Validation (HTML5): Element 'app-root' is not supported(mentioned in screenshot)

Please help me out how to initialize angular in ASP.NET WebForm?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJphi.png)

Comment: The "problem" is that you are directly linking the Angular markup, so the ASP.NET validator will try to validate the markup of the Angular component. And (rightly so) finds that `<app-root></app-root>` isn't valid HTML, but it is valid Angular markup. You should be able to just ignore that, as long as the Angular runtime can correctly run and convert it's markup to correct HTML

Comment: "I am integrating Angular 8 with ASP.NET WebForm"....why? You've got 2 competing UI frameworks there, one of which is very legacy. It's not a good recipe for success, and is a probably a great way to cause confusion and extra problems. If this is a new project, consider using Web API as the back end instead. If it's a legacy project, consider whether trying to sticky-tape an Angular app onto the front is really a good idea.

Comment: Angular is not able to convert the markup, Insteam I am getting error like "The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.s"

Comment: @ADyson Yes its a legacy project, I am trying to combine Angular and work with it. Its working with mvc but I am not able to use the app-root with webforms.

Comment: Why would you want to combine 2 UI frameworks in one application? That's going to get messy, as you've discovered. There might be a better approach to whatever feature you're trying to implement here. P.s. Angular+MVC is also illogical for the same reason - two UI frameworks in one application. A client side UI framework needs an API as its server side backend, not a server-side UI framework.

Comment: @ADyson, the main landing page is in webforms(default.aspx), in that I have to create some highcharts and all. so any better idea to combine these charts in .aspx page.

Comment: HighCharts doesn't require Angular. See https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation . So my suggestion would be, if you want to use HighCharts then just use HighCharts by itself. JavaScript works perfectly fine in an aspx page (since it's just a web page, when it's rendered to the browser). Not sure where you think Angular comes into it, just for displaying some charts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644123/the-selector-my-app-did-not-match-any-elements or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839390/validationhtml5-element-t-is-not-supported solve your problem?